# Craps Game Java

Tags: java, random, methods, printing

I am supposed to be making a game of craps in java, but I have a problem. You see, technically the game is finished, but it will not say if you loose the game or not even if you do. It will only continue to roll til you win. I tried a couple workarounds but it only seems to trap it in an infinite loop. 
Game rules:
Roll two dice. Each die has six faces representing values 1, 2, …, and 6, respectively.
Check the sum of the two dice. If the sum is 2, 3, or 12 (called craps), you
lose; if the sum is 7 or 11 (called natural), you win; if the sum is another value
(i.e., 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, or 10), a point is established. Continue to roll the dice until either
a 7 or the same point value is rolled. If 7 is rolled, you lose. Otherwise, you win.

```
Example run:
You rolled 4 + 4 = 8
point is 8
You rolled 6 + 2 = 8
You win
```

Here is my code as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
public class CrapsGame
{

   public static void main (String[]args)
   {



      String restart = "y";
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      int sum=rollDice();
      int points = points(sum);
      boolean youWin=youWin(sum, points);  

      while(restart.equals("y")){
         youWin=false;
         while(youWin==false){
            rollDice();
            sum=rollDice();
            points=points(sum);
            youWin=youWin(sum, points);
         }


         System.out.print("\nWould you like to play again? y or n: ");
         restart = scan.next();
      }
      System.out.print("The program has ended!"); 
   }
   public static int rollDice() 
   {
      int num1= (int)(6.0*Math.random() + 1.0); //first die
      int num2= (int)(6.0*Math.random() + 1.0); //second die
      int sum= num1 + num2; //sum of roll
      System.out.printf("\nYou have rolled %d + %d = %d\n", num1, num2, sum);  //Prints the sum
      return sum;
   }


   public static int points(int sum)
   {  
      int points=0;
      if (sum>=4 && sum<=6) {  //Counts points based on your rolls
         points = points + 1;
         System.out.print("Your points are: " + points);
      }
      else if (sum>=8 && sum<=10){
         points = points + 1;
         System.out.print("Your points are: " + points);
      }
      return points;
   }

   public static boolean youWin(int sum, int points)
   {  
      boolean youWin=false;
      if (sum==2 || sum==3 || sum == 12) {
         youWin=false;
         System.out.print("You lost with a " + sum);  //Determines if you win or loose based on the sum and points and returns the youWin boolean
      }
      else if (sum==7 || sum==11) {
         youWin=true;
         System.out.print("You won with a " + sum);
      }
      else if (points==7){
         youWin=true;
      }
      return youWin;
   }

}
```

Comment: 1. Remove all the noises in your code.  Remove all those meaningless comments and codes which is irrelevant to your question.  2. You should be clear on how your behavior deviate from the expected behavior.  3. Just learn to use a debugger and trace it.  Normally this kind of problem is easy to spot with help of debugger

Comment: I will do so, I have to have all that nonsense there because that is what my professor wants me to have. It is not helpful I know.

Comment: You will need that in your homework, but not in the question here.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that :/ I always forget to remove the comments because I want to post it while I am thinking about it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this method:

```
youWin=youWin(sum, points)
```

needs to return more than 2 types.  It should:

- return a value if you definitely lose
- return a value if you definitely win
- return a value if you establish a point.

Comment: I am looping because it is supposed to continue to print the sum and add points until you win or you get craps. I will update with the game's rules.